# Error downloading Golang libraries from VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

By running the following command in cmd or vscode:

```
go get -u -v github.com/mdempsky/gocode
```

I received the following console error:

```
crypto/internal/cipherhw
crypto/rc4
runtime
# crypto/rc4
c:\go\src\crypto\rc4\rc4_asm.go:13:18: (*Cipher).XORKeyStream redeclared 
in this block
previous declaration at c:\go\src\crypto\rc4\rc4.go:61:6
```

I have already checked the GOPATH, and GOROOT. I also uninstalled and installed go and VSCode again and was unsuccessful.

Comment: Does this work in a terminal?

Comment: @ollien does not work

Comment: You have a corrupt Go installation. As part of [issue 25417](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25417) the assembly rc4 implementation was removed. You probably have a left over `rc4_asm.go` file from a previous version of Go. You should completly/cleanly uninstall Go and re-install Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a declaration error, if you inspect the error code you can fix it yourself.

> > crypto\rc4\rc4_asm.go:13:18: (*Cipher).XORKeyStream redeclared 
> >     in this block
> >
> > previous declaration at c:\go\src\crypto\rc4\rc4.go:61:6

The first line states that (*Cipher).XORKeyStream was redeclared on line 13 of the file rc4_asm.go

So if you inspect the rc4.go, file at line 61, you will find that (*Cipher).XORKeyStream has been defined more than once. Keep the definition you need, and go build again.

I should note that one of the steps of go getting is a go build, so you don't have to worry about re-downloading again and again.

I would try removing the download and trying again however, I managed to use that command and got an error free build.

Comment: "Keep the definition you need, and go build again" is bad advice; this is part of the Go standard library and a build failure there suggests a corrupt Go installation.